# R how to produce a vector trimming another vector by choosing a fixed value of its components

Tags: r, vector, trim

This is an elementary question; I apologize for it.
Let `x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)`. I would like to produce a vector `z` of length 5 s.t. its components are all those `x` satisfying the condition

if `x[i]>2` then write `2`.

The result should look like

```
z <- c(1,2,2,2,2)
```

I know that

```
z <- which(x>2)
```

gives me

```
3 4 5
```

but I cannot find a good way to implement it to arrive at the result.
I thank you all for your support.

EDIT. If instead of considering a vector `x` I have a matrix `M` with columns `x` and `y` and I want to apply the above trimming to the column `x` leaving `y` untouched, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
y <- x
y[x>2] <- 2
1 2 2 2 2
```

---

If you've a `matrix M` with two columns, and you want to replace only the first column with values > 2 to 2, then do:

```
M[,1][M[,1]>2] <- 2
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works. It is interesting to me ('couse I am no profi) the need of introducing `y` as `x` and then use `x` again.

Comment: @agstudy, I was thinking of the case where the value to be replaced is not 2 (for ex: 3, would result in `(1,2,3,3,3)`). But I thought your solution was specifically meant for this. So deleted the comment.

Comment: @agstudy If instead of considering a vector `x` I have a matrix `M` with columns `x` and `y` and I want to apply the above trimming to the column `x` leaving `y` untouched, how should I proceed? `M[M$x>2,] <- 2` makes no sense...

Comment: @Avitus, you should do `M[,1][M[,1]>2] <- 2` where `[,1]` is the index of column `x`.

Comment: @Arun thanks a lot! Please feel free to move your comment into an answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pmin`:

```
pmin(x, 2)
# [1] 1 2 2 2 2
```